# how to set x position to selected vertices

Tags: modeling

I want to make sure vertices of an entire edge loop have the same x position.

I've selected the vertices, set pivot center to individual origins and typed 0 in the x position transform in properties.

They don't move to 0.
[image]

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected because you're moving the "median" of all selected vertices, and not the individual x values

Answer (score 10):

After selecting the loop that you want to position, you can drag your mouse over the X value in the properties menu (it shows up when you press the <kbd>N</kbd> key)

[image]

If you have vertices that are offset from the center but their average X value is zero (as shown):

[image]

You can use the following keystrokes to set the x position of each vertex to zero :

<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/cNQN9  Sorry cannot figure out how to include an image. This link shows two selected verts slightly offset from the center line - the x position in properties says 0 after I type it but they are NOT at zero. I'm used to Maya where you can type in the channel box with multiple verts selected and all will be moved. Is this possible in Blender?

Comment: @lawrencehagman Okay, I think that is showing the average x position. To align them so that they both have a value of x=0, select both of the vertices, hit s to scale, then x to constrain on the x axis, then 0 to bring them to the median point. I think that's what you're looking for: x>s>0.

Comment: If you want to position them on X=0 on the world coordinates, use **Global** instead of **Local** for the transformation.

Comment: Hi, I'm using global and it's still giving me the average position. When click on the pivot center pulldown it says "Bounding Box", I select "Individual Elements". The results are the same.

Comment: @lawrencehagman Did you try S+X+0 ?

Comment: Thank you. S+X+0 works but I'm trying to understand why the properties transform input fields try to average the positions of what is selected. There must be a setting somewhere that I'm missing. I've tried global and local, I've changed pivot points. Huh.

Comment: @lawrencehagman So what do you eventually want to happen? If you select a single vertex, it should tell you its location, but if you select more than one, it will tell you the average. Are you saying that you expect it to change depending on the pivot point?

Comment: I'm was a maya user so I'm just trying to get how to use blender. I'd expect when you type 0 into a transform value field that value would affect everything selected. For all selected, set transform x to the input.

Comment: @lawrencehagman first place the 3D cursor at the global origin (0,0,0) and then choose "3D Cursor" as the pivot centre. That should place the vertices absolutely. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, what you want to achieve is not directly supported in the UI. However, there are at least three workarounds.

As starting point, lets assume that we are in mesh edit mode (select the object and press tab to enter edit mode), and we have a reference point somewhere in the mesh, which already has the correct coordinate value (the question is regarding X coordinate, but it could be any).

- Copy-paste numeric value for each point individually: select the reference value, ctrl-C from the coordinate in the Properties panel (press N to show that panel). Then select each point *individually* and paste in the coordinate value.
- Use snap-to-vertex for each point individually. Activate the snapping mode, then select one vertex, press "g" (grab) followed by the coordinate constraint ("x" for x coord etc). Then drag with the mouse close to the reference point.
- Scaling-Trick: use the reference point as pivot, then scale all other points to zero relative to the pivot, and use the appropriate coordinate constraint. In practice:

  - either use the 3D cursor as pivot: then select the reference point, snap the cursor to active (shift-s o). Then select all the other points, and press "s" (scale) "x" (the coordinate constraint) and then enter the numeric Zero.
  - or alternatively use the active point as pivot: thus select all points, and then select the reference point *as last one* (which is the active point, showed as white marker). Then press again "s" "x" "0"

Further hint: frequently the reference geometry or point exists already within another mesh. You can duplicate it from there, separate it and join it into the mesh you are currently working on. When done with your adjustments, you can Mesh > Clean-up > delete loose

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to set positions. Not talking about set transform amounts or medians here, but setting the position of a point or multiple points.
In lightwave, for example, there was a "set value" numerical. It was great for precision modeling.
After going through a number of forums, I can't find anything of this sort in blender. It would make a great little add on though.

Comment: Welcome to bse. When you have sufficient rep, you can comment on posts IMO this should be a comment.

Answer (score -1):

This is easy. Just do as above to get them alligned S X 0 or S Y 0 etc. To get the all to a specific place just hit tab go into edit mode. Select the vertices or edges you want. Press N to bring up Transform menu. Change the Median from Local to Global and type in your position in x, y or z

Comment: Mike, how does this differ from  the other answer/?

Comment: My apologies I did not see cegatons answer. Although I was just adding clarity.